# How to match multiple values in a single table in a single query all at the same time

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want to match multiple values in a single query in a single time. like the things which i have done. i want to match the values of different questions with the different answers for which i have made the group of conditions as you can see in the below code. but this code is not working for me.

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `tb_user_answers`
WHERE   (
`question_id` = '1'
AND `answer_id` = '2'
 )
AND   (
`question_id` = '2'
AND `answer_id` IN(4, 6)
 )
AND   (
`question_id` = '3'
AND `answer_id` IN(8, 9, 10)
 )
```

there is a compulsion that we need to fetch those records which are perfectly matched with these condition. so i think we can't use the OR instead of AND as we need all the conditions should be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy all the criteria you could use aggregation and having filter for the filters, Below query will return user_id s who have all these conditions satisfied not only single one but all.

```
SELECT `user_id`
FROM `tb_user_answers`
GROUP BY  `user_id`
HAVING SUM(`question_id` = '1' AND `answer_id` = '2') > 0
   AND SUM(`question_id` = '2' AND `answer_id` IN(4, 6)) > 0
   AND SUM(`question_id` = '3' AND `answer_id` IN(8, 9, 10)) > 0
```